# Tokenize text containing digits

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, text-classification

I want to create a text-classifier, the input to the model contains digits along with the text that contains important information (don't think I can just throw away the digits). Is there a way to tokenize this kind of input?

The input looks like this:

```
     input:
     -------
     Please have a look at case#345
     injector 1 and injector 3 is not responding for model 8
     Car has been running for 2345 km, try to do this procedure 
     .....
     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

text = 'Please have a look at case#345. injector1 and injector3 is not responding for model8. Car has been running for 2345 km, try to do this procedure .'
# tokenize the document
result = text_to_word_sequence(text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['please', 'have', 'a', 'look', 'at', 'case', '345', 'injector1', 'and', 'injector3', 'is', 'not', 'responding', 'for', 'model8', 'car', 'has', 'been', 'running', 'for', '2345', 'km', 'try', 'to', 'do', 'this', 'procedure']
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Would it be better to consider injector1 ("injector1") as a complete word, and not two words ("injector", "1")? If I have more rows with the sentence "Injector 1"? Or would the model learn equally good?

Comment: I would recommend injector1. in the current case injector and 1 act as two different tokens. while doing the preprocessing merge the injector and 1 as injector1

Comment: Updated the answer with those string and single-digit word combinations..